# Subclassing numpy arrays with axis-specific attributes

Tags: python, numpy, oop

I am trying to implement a subclass of `np.ndarray` with extra attributes. I would like these attributes to be passed to views of this instance.

Plagiarizing what's in the [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html), I ended up with this class that works pretty well as far as I can tell, even though I am not really sure (yet) what's happening in `__array_finalize__`.

```
class InfoArray(np.ndarray):
    """
    An array with extra attributes, being passed on to views and results of
    ufuncs.
    """
    def __new__(cls, array, *args, **kwargs):
        # Input array is an already formed ndarray instance
        # We first cast to be our class type
        obj = np.asarray(array).view(cls)
        # add the new attributes to the created instance
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(obj, key, value)
        # Finally, we must return the newly created object:
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        """
        This function ensures that attributes are present in all ways instances
        are created, including views on the array.
        """
        if type(obj) is not np.ndarray:
            for key, value in vars(obj).items():
                setattr(self, key, value)

    def __array_wrap__(self, obj, context=None):
        """Ensure that scalar type is returned instead of 0D array"""
        if obj.shape == ():
            return obj[()] # if ufunc output is scalar, return it
        else:
            return np.ndarray.__array_wrap__(self, obj)
```

Now is when it gets tricky. I need to implement another subclass, that would ideally inherit from `InfoArray` and would carry **axis-specific** attributes. My final goal would be for that lower-dimensional views of my instances to have *truncated* attributes.

As I am not sure if what I'm asking is clear, I'll give a specific example. I need a `MedicalImage` class that stores a `spacing` attribute that represents the distance between two elements of the array along each axis. This `spacing` is for instance used for gradients computations.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class MedicalImage(InfoArray):
    """A medical image (usually 2 or 3 dimensions)"""
    def __init__(self, array, spacing=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """Ensure a spacing attribute is present"""
        if spacing is None:
            spacing = np.ones(self.ndim)
        self.spacing = np.asarray(spacing)

    def gradients(self):
        """Compute spacing-aware gradients"""
        result = np.moveaxis(np.array(np.gradient(self)), 0, -1)
        result /= self.spacing
        return result
```

This is working quite for simple use-cases.

```
In [3]: image = MedicalImage(np.arange(25).reshape((5,5)),
                             spacing=[1,2],
                             patient_name='john doe')

In [4]: image.gradients()[0,0]
Out[4]: array([5. , 0.5])
```

Gradients take spacing into account, that's nice.

Attributes are also preserved for views:

```
In [5]: image[5].patient_name
Out[5]: 'john doe'
```

Now, let's get to the axis-specific attributes:

```
In [6]: image[0].spacing
Out[6]: array([1, 2])  # Desired output: array([1]) or just 1

In [7]: image.T.spacing
Out[7]: array([1, 2])  # Desired output: array([2, 1])
```

This would allow a nice `image.T.gradients()` to return a coherent result.

PS: I'm aware of the existence of [nibabel](http://nipy.org/packages/nibabel/index.html), [medpy](https://github.com/loli/medpy), [simpleitk](http://www.simpleitk.org/) (...) but I'm doing this for educational purposes.